# Porting VisualStudio (2008) Project to Linux

Tags: linux, makefile, porting

I'm trying to port a wide Visual Studio (2008) Project to Linux System.

Do somebody know if it exist a way to easly *"transform"* the `.vcproj` file into a `makefile`?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest would be to just learn how to write your own Makefile. It's quite simple.

But other than that you could try http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28908/Tool-for-Converting-VC-2005-Project-to-Linux-Makef

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears, this tool depends on Windows to even compile.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you, but you need to handle whit you outputs in the original code

Make-It-so

http://code.google.com/p/make-it-so/

or 
sln2mak

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28908/Tool-for-Converting-VC-2005-Project-to-Linux-Makef

i hope this can help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use Winemaker, which is part of WINE: something all major distributions already include.

On Fedora, which use yum, you can, as root, run yum install /usr/bin/winemaker to install it. This will probably also work on other yum based operating system, but you may have to provide another path, if winemaker is packaged to install in /usr/bin (which I doubt will be the case).

Once you have  converted the project, consider using Autotools instead -- it's, in my experience, by far the simplest build tool available and is very easy to learn and use. Just don't be scared to poor documentation you will often find lying around. The only files you have to edit are configure.ac and Makefile.am files.